# declaring array in javascript object crashes browser

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some objects using JavaScript.  I have 1 small object that appears to be working but this object needs a multi-dimensional array.

When I try to use this snippet of this object my browser crashes...

Are there any good tutorials on how to write objects in javascript?

```
function map(sizeX, sizeY)
{
    var cityArr = new Array();
    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;
    this.generateCity = generateCity;
    var cityXY = new Array();

    function generateCity(cityNum)
    {
        alert(cityNum);
    }
}
```

When I call this, it fails when I add the call to generateCity method my browser cashes.

```
var objMap = new map();
//objMap.generateCity(2);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which browser does this crash? I don't see anything wrong with the code that might reasonably cause that.

Comment: I'm using IE 10 - Win8

Comment: Don't know. Running under Chromium 18.0.1025.151 (64 bit ubuntu), I get an alert box that says 2.

Comment: Have you tried using this snippet on its own empty page? I am getting no crashes.

Comment: I tried in IE10 and I get an alert box that says "2" - no crash.

Comment: your array may be very long .

Answer (score 3):

First off, some JavaScript best practices:

1. use `[]` to create a new array, not `new Array()`,
2. use capital letters for constructor functions, so `function Map(...) {...}`, not `map(...)`,
3. don't reference functions before declaring them, so put your `function generateCity(cityNum)` before your `this.generateCity = generateCity`,
4. use `console.log`, not `alert`,
5. if you're building an object, define your object as one by putting its function on its prototype.

That means doing this:

```
function Map(sizeX, sizeY)
{
   this.sizeX = sizeX;
   this.sizeY = sizeY;
   // you're not using these arrays. Why are they in your example code?
   var cityArr = [],
       cityXY = [];  
}

Map.prototype = {
  sizeX: 0, // Some default values, shared by all instances
  sizeY: 0, // unless overriden in the constructor function.
  generateCity: function(cityNum) { 
    // let's not block the entire page by using alert.
    console.log("cityNum: " + cityNum);
  }
}
```

So, with that said, this code works just fine, as can be seen on http://jsfiddle.net/mtr24 (run with your console open, and you'll see "cityNum: 2" being printed.

Comment: Ok I think I need to step back and understand how to create Javascript objects before I go any further. Do you have any tutorial URLs that would benefit me?  I want to make sure I'm doing it correctly more than just having it work.

Comment: @webdad3 To continue shamelessly plugging my answer on prototype and constructor functions, inheritance and overriding functions you can check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 If you have any question I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the prototype but setting the prototype like you do will direct the Map.prototype.constructor to Object instead of Map

Comment: relevant for inheritance, not necessarily relevant in this case. That said, worth mentioning.